# How to convert TypedDict definition to dataclass definition

Tags: python, types, python-dataclasses, typeddict

I would like to convert automatically TypedDict definition into Dataclasses definition

For example, this code contains duplication of code:

```py
from typing_extensions import TypedDict
from dataclasses import dataclass

class Square(TypedDict):
  l : float

@dataclass
class DataClassSquare:
  l : float
```

I would like to do something like that:

```py
from typing_extensions import TypedDict
from dataclasses import dataclass

class Square(TypedDict):
  l : float

DataClassSquare = converter(Square)
```

But I do not know how to write the converter.

Any idea?

Comment: This will make the type checker and IDE unable to perceive which attributes `DataClassSquare` has.

Comment: I know, but this is not important in my situation fortunately